# Is there any equivalent to index.js in C++?

Tags: c++, include, c-preprocessor

In JavaScript, I can do `import "/my-folder"` and it will import `/my-folder/index.js"`. 
Is there some equivalent filename in C++? (so that `#include "my-folder"` will include `my-folder/filename.fileext`)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there is not equivalent to `index.js` in standard C++. It would however be perfectly legal for a specific compiler to implement something like that, though I'm not aware of any compiler that does. Quoting from 19.2 [cpp.include] [(N4659)](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2017/n4659.pdf):

> (1) A `#include` directive shall identify a header or source file that can be processed by the implementation.
>
> (3) A preprocessing directive of the form
>
> ```
> # include " q-char-sequence " new-line
> ```
>
> causes the replacement of that directive by the entire contents of the source file identified by the specified sequence between the `"` delimiters. **The named source file is searched for in an implementation-defined manner.**

Emphasis mine.

I'm not sure what role `index.js` typically plays in JavaScript libraries, but if you're trying to implement a portable catch-all header for your library (so that the end users only need to include a single header instead of many), you'll just have to write your own header to serve that purpose. Headers named along the lines of `my_folder/my_folder.h` or `my_folder/prelude.h` would be common candidates.